# Finding an irregularly repeatable integer-pattern in an array in C (without traversing the array multiple times)

Tags: c, arrays

A pattern of the integers 2,1,4 is irregularly repeated in an array of 5000 elements, with rest of the elements in the array being 0. But 2 is always followed by 1, and 1 is always followed by 4, then 2 again and so on...

For example:-

> 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 2 0 0 0 0 0 1 0 0 0 0 0 4 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 2 0 0 0 0 1 0 0 0 4 0 0 0 0 0 2 0 0 1 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 4 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 2 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 1 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 4 0 0 0 0 0......and so on.

I want to check if this 2-1-4 pattern is repeated in the array, irrespective of the number of 0's between the elements.

If this pattern, however irregular, is repeated, then I have a correct array. Else I have missed some elements.

How can I go about this ??

Edit:- This be done without traversing the array multiple times with simple C language code.

Comment: `C` OR `C++` The best answer will differ considerably based on which language it is, so choose one or the other, since they are quite different.

Comment: Sound like a job for a state machine. Which begs the question: Is an array that contains only zeros considered to be matching the pattern?

Comment: That's counter productive, and makes for a lesser quality question (which is already too broad for SO, even if you *do* settle for one language).

Comment: @EOF:- Nope, an array containing only zeroes means absolutely no data is received, and hence deemed incorrect.

Comment: @Abhishek: In that case, make the state machine's initial state nonaccepting.

Comment: Remove 0s and cross correlation?

Comment: @StoryTeller No, the best answer will be the most effective, most readable answer. Just because a C++ solution contains STL and more than ten C++14 buzzwords, it doesn't automatically turn into a good one. More likely, it turns into an awfully ineffective, unreadable mess. I see no reason why a C++ solution would look much different than a C one for such a simple task.

Comment: @Lundin, most readable is highly subjective. To one it will be a function written using the verbs provided in the c++ standard library, to another it may be written using Duff's Device. Our own individual preferences seem quite clear on this.

Comment: Well, since this question is put on-hold for being broad, i have narrowed its solution down to C. Currently i have implemented Puck's answer and finding it effective.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The easy way would be to read each element of the array in a loop and store the last interesting element (2, 1 or 4) in a temp variable. And when another interesting element occurs, you check is this is the one you want, you continue, else, your array is bad.

```
int isArrayBad(int * array, int arraySize)
{
int temp = 0;
for(int i = 0; i<arraySize; i++)
{
    if(!temp && array[i])
        temp = array[i];
    else if(array[i])
    {
        switch(temp)
        {
        case 2:
            if(array[i] != 1)
                return -1;
            break;
        case 1:
            if(array[i] != 4)
                return -1;
            break;
        case 4:
            if(array[i] != 2)
                return -1;
            break;
        }
        temp = array[i];
    }
}
return 0;
}
```

Comment: Yes, will try this. Please vote-up though...

Comment: Implemented this snippet and moving ahead...Thanks a lot!!

Answer (score 3):

Walk the sequence accumulating integers from the set `(1, 2, 4)`, and skipping all other numbers. Every time you have accumulated three numbers, check that you have a `(2, 1, 4)` sequence. If you do, discard the accumulated numbers, and continue; otherwise, declare the sequence invalid, and stop processing.

Upon reaching the end of the sequence check that you have no accumulated numbers. If you do, make sure that it's either a single number `2`, or two numbers `(2, 1)`. Otherwise, the sequence is invalid.

This translates in a very simple program:

```
bool checkValid(std::vector<int> &data) {
    int acc = 0;
    bool res = false;
    for (auto &n : data) {
        // Skip numbers other than 1, 2, 4
        if (n != 1 && n != 2 && n != 4) {
            continue;
        }
        // Do accumulation in an int
        acc = 10*acc + n;
        // If we reach the target, zero out and continue
        if (acc == 214) {
            acc = 0;
            // Now that we found 2, ... , 1, ..., 4,
            // the sequence may be considered valid,
            // unless we find an error later on.
            res = true;
            continue;
        }
        // Check if the partial accumulation is valid
        if (acc != 2 && acc != 21) {
            return false;
        }
    }
    return res;
}
```

Comment: Read the question again. The sequence 214 can have a padding of 0s amongst them so 20000100004 is also valid for example.

Comment: Ah, I get it. Nice one +1.

Comment: What if the array ends while you are not in an accepting state? I'd write an explicit state machine, easier to reason about.

Comment: @EOF Of course, state machine is the first thing that comes to mind when one sees a problem like this. However, I suspect that OP may not have enough theoretical background to reason about this problem in terms of a state machine, let alone independently implementing even a small state machine. That's why I decided against swatting this particular fly with a sledgehammer, even though theoretically that would be the most efficient way.

Comment: I'm with EOF. This is a good learning example how to use state machines.  Drawing it is trivial. The basic flow is `Initial -> 2 -> 1 -> 4(Accepted)` with obvious alternative flows to `NotAccepted`, a link back from 4 to 2 (when the pattern repeats itself), and formally a idempotent transition for input 0 (i.e. no state change).

Comment: Unfortunately, the OP has clarified that an all-zero array is not accepted. As far as I can tell, your solution doesn't fulfill that requirement.

Comment: @EOF That's easy to fix, though - takes about 20 seconds :-)

Comment: @dasblinkenlight: But it *does* somewhat reduce the "very simple" part. State machine.

Comment: @EOF State machine change in response to this clarification would have been a lot more complex, though: a state machine-based solution would need three extra states for what I was able to accomplish by introducing a `bool` variable.

Comment: @dasblinkenlight: Your `acc` variable holds how many states? Also, it seems to me that your function will accept the sequences `2142` and `21421`, not just `214214`. I'm not sure whether that is the OP's intent. Oh well, seems the question is badly specified...

Answer (score 3):

Your data is in a `vector` of `integers`. The solution could be something like (C++11):

```
std::vector<int> data;
//fill your data here
data.erase(std::remove(data.begin(), data.end(), 0), data.end());
auto is_ok=true;
for(auto it=data.begin();it!=data.end();it=std::advance(it,3)){
    if(*it!=2 && *(std::next(it))!=1 && *(std::advance(it,2))!=4){
        is_ok=false;   
        break;
    }
    if(std::next(it)==data.end() || std::advance(it,2)==data.end()){
          //This is a special case that you should do it by yourself depending on the requirement 
          break;
    }
}
```

Comment: I'm pretty sure it can be made prettier with some more uses of stuff from `algorithm`. A repeated use of [`std::mismatch`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/mismatch) may make this clearer.

Comment: @StoryTeller Feel free to propose an edit or to enhance on it and post it as new answer

Comment: I'm viewing this through the SE mobile app, won't be doing any editing or answering like this :)

Comment: This is going to be outrageously slow compared with a simple loop that checks integer values... Consider using C instead.

Answer (score 3):

I would go for a function which finds the first mis-matching element; if it finds no mismatch, an end-of-input pointer is returned.

In C:

```
int *mismatch(int *arr, size_t len)
{
    int expected = 2;
    int *end = arr + len;
    for (; arr < end; ++arr) {
        if (*arr != 0 && *arr != expected) {
            return arr;
        }

        switch (*arr) {
            case 2: expected = 1; break;
            case 1: expected = 4; break;
            case 4: expected = 2; break;
            default: break;
        }
    }
    return arr;
}
```

A more C++'esque version would not use raw pointers but some iterator type, i.e.. It would also use a range (i.e. an end iterator) instead of a length:

```
template <typename Iterator>
Iterator mismatch(Iterator begin, Iterator end)
{
    typename Iterator::value_type expected = 2;
    for (; begin != end; ++begin) {
        if (*begin != 0 && *begin != expected) {
            return begin;
        }

        // dito
    }
}
```

You should also consider what to do with empty sequences (i.e. length zero) or all-zero sequences. Or incomplete sequences (e.g. just `2`).

Comment: why a template function though!? Seems a bit excessive.

Comment: I think some flavour of the first snippet is the correct solution for both C and C++. There should never be a reason to write ineffective code no matter language.

Comment: @Lundin The first snippet would be somewhat inefficient if the sequence of numbers was actually stored as e.g. a `std::list` or maybe even a custom data structure. The fact that C++ permits efficiently abstracting over types is actually quite useful: note that plain raw iterators are valid random-access-iterators, so the second version would be equivalent to the first in C++ when given plain `int*` values. Since the OP didn't specify any context, it's not possible to make any assumptions about what's "excessive" or "efficient" or "effective".

Comment: @FrerichRaabe Then don't store them in some std::ineffective container, but in a plain array. And I really don't see how type abstraction would be useful for an algorithm that checks for the integer values 2, 1 and 4. There is simply no other type but integer that makes sense.

Comment: `typename Iterator::value_type expected = 2;` Templates considered harmful. For this reason. Lol.

Comment: @Lundin A container which is ineffective (did you mean to write 'inefficient'?) for this particular operation may still be a good choice overall if the common operations are efficient. For instance, imagine if the input sequence commonly gets insertions/removals in the middle. The bottom line is that the C++ version will be no worse than the C version for data structures which use contiguous memory (e.g. arrays or `std::vector`), but -- unlike the C version -- it still permits using other containers.

Comment: There is nothing indicating that there are any insertions in the middle of the data so there is no need to cover that case. The fastest solution is likely not using pointers anyway, but integer iterators. Your switch statement will yield numerous branches. The optimal would be to have a local const array with the values 2,1,4 and using an index of that array. And as usual with C++, I will only believe that the template solution is equally fast when I see the disassembly.

Comment: @Lundin Sounds like a plan - let me know what your disassembly inspection yields.

Comment: @FrerichRaabe After modifying both your examples for const correctness, I tried the C example both with `gcc -O3` in C mode and in C++ mode, same machine code in both cases, 17 instructions all in all. Then I tried the C++ code with a std::vector, `g++ -std=c++14 -O3`, which yielded 60 instructions, out of which approximately 10-20 were related to filling up the std::vector and fiddling around with dynamic memory. Actual benchmarking would likely show that the C++ version is remarkably slower, mainly because of the incredibly ineffective std::vector and heap allocation.

Comment: (Your C++ example needs something like `Iterator start = begin; ... /*everything ok*/ return start;` for it to be compatible with the C example)

Comment: @Lundin Thumbs up for benchmarking! However, it seems that you rather profiled the performance of `std::vector` than the performance of the function template I sketched. My original claim was that the template is equivalent to the C code when given plain `int*` pointers. I.e. the code generated is no worse than what the C definition does (but the template permits being used with other containers).

Comment: @FrerichRaabe Essentially, the part of the code that is the function only is about 10 instructions versus 40 instructions. Give or take, with -O3 the function is inlined so it is not obvious where it begins and where it ends.

Answer (score 2):

I wrote this, but IMO the better way would be to (1) filter the array by creating a new one without the zeros or unwanted values, and (2) one pass through the new array, comparing against (x, y, z) as a circular linked list.

$ g++ main.cc -o main && ./main

```
// main.cc
#include <stdio.h>

class Checker {
private:
  static int pattern[];
  static int* const lastElem;
  static int ignore;
  int* next;
  int* advance(int*);
public:
  Checker();
  bool isCorrect(int* const, int* const);
};

int Checker::pattern[] = {2, 1, 4};
int* const Checker::lastElem = &pattern[2];
int Checker::ignore = 0;

Checker::Checker() {
  next = &pattern[0];
}

int* Checker::advance(int* cursor) {
  if(cursor != lastElem) {
    return ++cursor;
  }
  return &pattern[0];
}

bool Checker::isCorrect(int* const begin, int* const end) {
  for(int* pArr = begin; pArr != end; ++pArr) {
    if(*pArr == ignore) {
      continue;
    }

    if(*pArr != *next) {
      return false;
    }

    next = advance(next);
  }
  return true;
}

int main(int argc, char** argv) {
  int testArr[] = {0, 0, 0, 2, 0, 1, 0, 0, 4, 0, 0, 0, 2, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 4, 0, 0, 0, 2, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 4};
  Checker test;
  bool res = test.isCorrect(testArr, &testArr[sizeof(testArr)/sizeof(testArr[0])]);
  printf("Test: %s\n", res ? "passed" : "failed");
  return 0;
}
```

fast as hell